# Why Dart Polymer inlines/vulcanize main css file into <head> tag?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

**web/templates/ui-elements.html**

```dart
<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"/>
    <div class="classes from main-css file"></div>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="ui-elements.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="ui-icon" attributes="name" noscript>
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"/>
    <span class="fa fa-{{name}}"></span>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

...
```

**web/templates/ui-elements.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();
}

...
```

**web/main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

main() {
  initPolymer();
}

@whenPolymerReady
void onReady() {
}
```

**web/main.html** (entry file before `pub build`)

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="import" href="templates/ui_elements.html"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-element></app-element>
    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**web/main.html** (entry file after `pub build`)

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.min.js"></script><script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <style>
    ...HERE IS FULL CONTENT OF main.css...
    </style>
</head><body>
...
HERE ARE ELEMENTS THAT ALSO USE main.css, so it's also downloading
<polymer-element name="ui-icon" attributes="name" noscript>
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"/>
    <span class="fa fa-{{name}}"></span>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
...

 <script src="main.html.polymer.bootstrap.dart.js" async=""></script>
</body></html>
```

Related questions:

- How to avoid "inlining/vulcanazing" content of main.css file?
- Why creats Polymer such a big output file: `main.html.polymer.bootstrap.dart.js` (323kb), `polymer.min.js` (121kb), `webcomponents.min.js` (103kb). Does something change in the near future?
- There are also other files that Polymer doesn't include into compiled `main.html` automatically (please, see the screen):

  - `main.web_components.bootstrap.dart`
  - `main.dart.js`

[image]

Additional screen:

[image]

Comment: Have you investigated in the Browser devtools which files are actually loaded by the browser? I never did, but AFAIK not all files are actually loaded.

Comment: I've update question - I've added screen from devtool.

Comment: Did you build in debug or release mode? (looks like release). I don't think you can do much currently but ensure that the server serves these files gzipped which should reduce the size notable. I'm not aware of any planned optimizations (doesn't mean much but there were no announcements lately). I guess the next big step is the update to Polymer 0.8. Optimization should be mostly a post 1.0 task.

Comment: > Did you build in debug or release mode? I don't know Gunter. I just used `pub build -o path-to/build-folder`. Thank for information concerning gzip and the future.

Comment: `release` then, it is the default on the console (`debug` would result in much bigger output).

Comment: Gunter, when I should use debug mode?

Comment: Debug mode produces unminified and not treeshaken output which results in more and much bigger but more readable files. As the name says this is for debugging purposes only. I think that sourcemap files are also only created in debug mode (can be enabled for release I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this behavior in the Polymer transformer config in the `pubspec.yaml` file like

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    ... 
    inline_stylesheets:
      web/asset/examples.css: false
      lib/asset/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css: false
```

Comment: Please, Gunter could you explain me why `pub build` generates separate `main.dart.js` file, but polymer transformer doesn't include it into `main.html` and include `main.html.polymer.bootstrap.dart.js` instead (I think it contains the actual `main.dart.js`. Also there is unused `main.web_components.bootstrap.dart` - what does it need for?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the resulting output files. You could check https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/script_inliner. Maybe it does what you want.

Comment: Polymer bootstraps your original entry point file as part of the transformer process, primarily to remove the use of mirrors and replace it with static code.

Comment: @JakeMacDonald, what is "remove the use of mirrors"? Could you explain in more details, please?

Comment: Polymer uses reflection (mirrors). Reflection prevents tree-shaking because you can potentially access/invoke anything in your dependencies. To fix that Polymer uses Smoke which uses reflection during development. For pub build the Smoke transformer generates reflection-less code so tree-shaking can be properly applied.